# Two-Dimensional List of Different Types

Tags: c#

I wonder if it is possible to create a two-dimensional `List` of different types. In other words, I wonder if something like this is possible:

```
List<T, U> list = new List<T, U>();
```

where `T` and `U` are any two different types.

Is it possible to achieve this without resorting to `struct`s or `class`es?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Are you trying to get something like a Dictionary? Or else, please explain yourself a little more?

Comment: I am trying to keep a list of indexes and values of type `int` and `string`, respectively.

Comment: Sounds like  a [`Dictionary<int, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to me.

Comment: I just looked up what a `Dictionary` is, and it seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you're looking for is a [`Dictionary<T,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary[3] = "three";
dictionary[7] = "seven";
foreach(var keyValuePair in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
// 3: three
// 7: seven
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this, but I'm not sure if this is what you need:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create<int, string>(2, "two"));
```

Comment: This is a good solution if OP needs to be able to map an integer to multiple strings. A `Dictionary` requires one value per key.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I disagree with that. You could simply have a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` (or even an `Hashset<string>` if he wants uniqueness within that key). The issue with the list of tuple is a key lookup will be in O(N). Now this might not be an issue if he's just iterating, but as soon as you want to lookup by the key, use a dictionary.

Comment: @SimonBelanger Yes, of course. That's what I'd go with as well. I said that this was a good solution, not that it was ideal.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`Dictionary<T, U>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

```
var list = new Dictionary<T, U>();
```

Where `T` and `U` the types are that you want.

Answer (score 0):

First approach: Inheritance. But you can go about and just create a `List<Object>`. Object doesn't care what you throw in there. But restricting that to two classes, no, that is not possible.

Comment: That's a bad idea on many level. He can put anything but he won't be able to access any properties without casting it. And for any two-valued 'object' you need a class or a structure, so might as well go ahead and create a class (which is what the question ask not to do). Regardless, if you want a List of Object, might as well use the old `ArrayList`, but advise against it.

Comment: I know, but it certainly works. But seeing the other answers given, I might have misunderstood the question.